# Need help optimizing this code for faster results

Tags: python, pandas, algorithm

To give an overview of the data, there are multiple rows of data which have the same id, and furthermore, have multiple columns with the same values. Now there are some functions which will output the same result for rows with the same `id`. Therefore, I group by this `id`, perform the functions I need to perform on them, and then I begin looping through each row within each group, to perform the functions which will yield different results for each row, even with the same id.

Here is some sample data:

```
id  map_sw_lon  map_sw_lat  map_ne_lon  map_ne_lat exact_lon exact_lat
1     10        15           11            16          20       30
1     10        15           11            16          34       50
2     20        16           21            17          44       33
2     20        16           21            17          50       60
```

Here is my code:

```
for id, group in df.groupby("id", sort=False):

   viewport = box(group["map_sw_lon"].iloc[0], 
   group["map_sw_lat"].iloc[0], group["map_ne_lon"].iloc[0], 
   group["map_ne_lat"].iloc[0])
   center_of_viewport = viewport.centroid
   center_hex = h3.geo_to_h3(center_of_viewport.y, center_of_viewport.x, 8)    

# everything above here can be done only once per group.   

# everything below needs to be done per row per group.
   for index, row in group.iterrows():

      current_hex = h3.geo_to_h3(row["exact_lat"], row["exact_lon"], 8)
      df.at[index,'hex_id'] = current_hex
      df.at[index, 'hit_count'] = 1

      df.at[index, 'center_hex'] = center_hex 
      distance_to_center = h3.h3_distance(current_hex, center_hex)
      df.at[index,'hex_dist_to_center'] = distance_to_center
```

This code works in around 5 mins for 1 million rows of data. The problem is I’m dealing with data much larger than that, and need something that works faster. I know it isn’t recommended to use for loops in Pandas, but I’m not sure how to solve this problem without using them. Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: Still struggling with this..any help would be appreciated!

Comment: It was your unmatched smart-quotes.

Comment: What is h3 in your code?

Comment: @jottbe https://eng.uber.com/h3/

Comment: (The red code colouring in code snippets is just a JavaScript syntax colouriser. It does not always get it right, but it looks OK here).

Comment: Have you ever tried to time the function calls of `geo_to_h3` and `h3_distance` as I mentioned? How much percentage of the total execution time is spent on those two  function calls?

Answer (score -1):

You need to do some profiling to see how much time each part of the code takes to run. I conjecture the most time consuming parts are the `geo_to_h3` and `h3_distance` calls. If so, other possible improvements on data frame operations (e.g., using `DataFrame.apply` and `GroupBy.transform`) would not help a lot.